# how to check if particular id exists in json object array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a Products array something like this

```
    Products[{product: {id: "Sss", name: "rttt", picture: "rrrrr"},
 quantity: 22},{product:{id:"tt",name:"qqq",picture:"iooo"}]
let item = Products.product.find((p) => p.productId === product.id);
```

I want to find the product with id tt in Angular 6 ,how to do this??

Comment: What have you tried so far? What was your attempt to find an object with particular id?

Comment: Don't need any framework to do it....is javascript array functionality. A simple web search would get you the answer

Comment: If only there was some sort of [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for finding things in an array.

Comment: OK. So now you added `find()` in question so what is the specific problem now? Take a few minutes to help others help you by reading through [ask]

Comment: `Products.product` makes no sense. Should be `Products`. But better write variables in camelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply `Array.find` on `Products.product` which is a single object (first item of `Products` array). Instead you should `find` over `Products`.

```js
var products = [{product :{id: "Sss", name: "rttt", picture: "rrrrr"}},{product:{id:"tt",name:"qqq",picture:"iooo"}}]
    
 var selProd = products.find(p => p.product.id === 'tt');
 
 console.log(selProd);
```

Comment: thanks i was just confused in accessing the inner json object :)